# what is causing knee pain after squats?

Tags: workout, squats, stronglifts, knee-pain

For several weeks now, I have noticed a mild pain on my right knee after squats, I am on strong lifts 5*5, 57Kg/179cm/M.

My squats weight reached 115 lbs but for the last two sessions have brought it down to 95 lbs to see if the pain is still there. Although its nothing like a pain that stops me from daily activities, but its more kind of a sensation that occurs during the day.

Upon searching about the form, I did the following things, I squat like I am about to sit on a chair, I discarded tennis shoes and used flat shoes, I keep my feet at 30 degrees and shoulder width apart.

Please advice me what can I do to avoid this pain and keep increasing weight seamlessly, thanks!

Comment: I experienced similar symptoms ("more kind of a sensation that occurs during the day") just after starting Stronglifts. Short answer:  (possibly) patellofemoral syndrome or runner's knee. This question (not mine) has details: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/persistent-mild-knee-pain-due-to-squats-push-through-or-stop?rq=1 . **See your doctor though. Don't self-diagnose.**

Comment: @JayrajI had taken a week's break in between, changed my technique a bit (push out knees a bit more) and saw some improvement on that sensation. However for the last couple of week I can feel it again, though this time it feels on a smaller area below the knee.

Comment: It can come and go (has done so for me). To treat patellofemoral syndrome, doctors usually prescribe rest, exercises to stretch the hamstrings, IT band and calf, and wall squats to strengthen the quads. Since you resumed squats after some rest, you did the "strengthen quads" part, but didn't do the stretches, which might be why it came back (all of this is speculation, I am not a doctor). If your doctor does diagnose you with patellofemoral syndrome, do the prescribed exercises. They really help, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

What helped for me were two things:

- Go a little deeper on the squats (just below parallel). It tends to relieve the pressure on the knees.
- Take longer rests between sets. I used to rest about 30 sec. to 1 minute between sets, but after having some pain in my knees I took 2-3 minutes of rest between sets & noticed to experience less pain.

And most importantly: if the pain continues, consider taking a break until the pain is gone. I know it's incredibly hard to do so (especially if you're doing 5x5), but it's worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

It could be joint fatigue from the repetitive movement.  Without X-rays and a proper check it is hard to tell.  I would try using knee wraps to keep the knee joint aligned.

Check them out here:

http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/drsquat12.htm