# Improving knee flexibility

Tags: flexibility, knees, quads

I've suffered from an injury in my knee the past 2 weeks or so. Yesterday I went to see a physiotherapist to see whats wrong. Long story short, my right knee is less flexible than my left one because the quad on the right leg is shorter and pulls my kneecap up a lot more than my left one.

I won't be able to do any heavy squats or deadlifts untill this injury is taken care of.

**Question:** What are some exercises to stretch my quad and make my knee more flexible?

**Additional info:**
Male, 26 years old, 1.84m , 75kg, about 8-9% bodyfat. Been doing sports since I was 5, 9 years of football, 5 years of cycling, been doing strength training for about 4 and a half years now, 2 years of which focussing on calisthenics and powerlifting.

Comment: Did your physio not suggest a few things for you?

Comment: @DarkHippo This was free consultancy so she helped establish the problem. I'm thinking about going for payed sessions so she can actually help me get rid of this. In the meantime I'm looking for some exercises I can do myself. I also think this could be useful information for others who want to get more flexible knees.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. It's honestly not a problem I've heard of before, but fair point, hopefully others will find it useful. I'd go for the paid consultancy were I you. Sorry I can't help more. Good luck

Comment: @MJB: I really suggest you visit a physio who is experienced with patella maltracking. It requires a careful rebalancing of the muscle strength/flexibility around the knee and depends on your condition which only a professional can assess. I had this problem and it took me a few physios until I found the right one. She used a combination of physio and manual therapy to fix it. I am not sure we can offer much help through the internet. You might find this question useful though: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/persistent-mild-knee-pain-due-to-squats-push-through-or-stop

Comment: @BKE Thanks for the feedback. I'm indeed looking in to going to a physiotherapist.

Comment: What caused the injury?